# How to use Google Takeout for YouTube data in an old YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, google-takeout

A while back Google prompted me to either change my youtube account so that it uses my Google+ profile, or keep the old account separate. I chose the latter option, and since then each time I load youtube I get asked whether I want to use youtube under my old alias account, or using the new account which has my real name.

The problem is that since this split into two accounts, Google Takeout seems to only export YouTube data of the new account, while all of my uploaded videos are in the old account...

Is there any way for me to export the videos from the old account?

Answer (score 3):

Go to [brand accounts](https://myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts), select the channel, click on view account details, select privacy, then scroll down to the data download option. (It's not in English for me so I don't know the exact labels.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally found a way to do this.

First go to https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced and click on the *"Change or add password"* option. This will redirect you to the channel's Google+ settings page. With this, **you can add an account password specifically for your G+ Page / YouTube channel account**, which will be assigned a login name looking like *username-1234@pages.plusgoogle.com*

Once  this is set up, *log out of your Google account* (or just open an Incognito session) and go to https://www.google.com/takeout, and *log in with the new page.plusgoogle.com user credentials* you just created. This should allow you to export your data now.

I've based this technique on similar instructions used to allow posting on Blogger using a Page instead of Profile, and it seems to work for me.